# Symfony4 UserInterface missing ->getId() how to access users id

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

why is there no  `getId()` method inside the `UserInterface` in Symfony 4? i tried to pass `UserInterface $user` to my Controller method to actually access the current logged in user's id with `$user->getId()`.  but this method simply doesent exist inside this interface - talking about best practice i should not simply add these method to the interface right?

i also tried to use my entity but was not able to access the current user object to fetch the id off the object.

first time sf4, am i getting it totally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony's `UserInterface` is part of the Security Component. The Security Component only cares about authentication. For the component, the `username` is the unique identifier of a user. It does not assume that your user has an id field. It only cares about the fields that matter for authentication purposes.

You should not inject the `UserInterface` in your controller method as a dependency, since it's not a service. Instead, Symfony provides a shorcut via the `$this->getUser()` method. That is typehinted to return a `UserInterface`. If you want typehinting to your concrete implementation, simply add on top of your controller class name as a docblock: `@method User|null getUser()`.

EDIT:

Added the `null` in the `@method User|null getUser()` so you are aware that that call may return null if there's no authenticated user. This will also help code intelligence tools to warn you against null pointer exceptions.

Comment: thanks for the additional explanation! nailed it for me

Comment: You're welcome. Also, you should check what `$this->getUser()` does behind the scenes. It calls a service called `TokenStorage`, where returns Symfony's auth token. If there's no authenticated user (meaning, no user stored in Symfon's Security Token) then `$this->getUser()` will return `null`

Answer (score 1):

You get get the current logged in user without the UserInterface (you don't need it) like this:

```
$user = $this->getUser()
```

To get the `Id` of the user you can use:

```
$user = $this->getUser()->getId();
```